# Is JSON data a string or a dictionary in Flask?

Tags: python, json, dictionary, flask, python-requests

This may be a silly question but I am really confused(I am a newbie). I am trying to make an API that accepts JSON as input and I am using Flask. The API takes POST method, so when a request comes along, it gets the JSON data from the body using

`data = requests.get_json()`

I expect data to be a string because, if I am not mistaken, JSON is nothing but a formatted string.

So, I do `data = json.loads(data)` But, my flask app crashes because it says data is a dictionary not a string. Of course, I can fix it by not using `json.loads` But it just bothers me and I wonder why I get a dictionary not a string.

Here is how I send test-requests, which seriously confuse me

1)

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('some.csv')
data = data.iloc[[0]].to_json(orient='records') // get the first row into json
res = requests.post(url, json=data) // I get a string in my Flask app.
```

2. 

```
import requests
data = {'name':'foo','age':99}
res = requests.post(url, json=data) // I get a dictionary in my Flask app.
```

3. 

```
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
const json = {'name':'foo','age':99};
xhr.open("POST",url);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json");
xhr.send(JSON.stringify(json)); // Though stringified, I get a dictionary in my Flask app. Why?
```

I am not sure if you can see my confusion. In some cases, I get a dictionary, and in some other cases I get a string. So, I am confused and don't know how to design my API and handle the requests.
Thank you in advance for your attention!

Comment: `pandas.DataFrame.to_json` returns a string.

Comment: ```data = json.loads(data)``` takes a string variable (data) and turns it into a dictionary.

Comment: JSON stands for JavaScript Object Notation - a way to serialise JavaScript objects into a string following a specific notation. In short, JSON is really a string with a specific encoding. Some APIs you have encountered here has differing viewpoints as to what a method with the name `json` should return or accept as an argument.

Comment: Following that, your issue really lies with how `requests.post` handle the `json` argument - it will implicitly call something like `json.dumps` before submitting the request, so your first example, the `to_json` output, which was already a string, gets doubly encoded into a JSON string type containing the JSON encoding of the underlying object (or dict). So when it got to the endpoint receiving that payload, it will decode that correctly and see that as a string (of the JSON encoded payload produced by `to_json`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pandas' [`DataFrame.to_json`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html) returns a string (`str`). Hence, in this code

```python
data = df.to_json(orient='records')
res = requests.post(url, json=data)
```

`data` is actually a `str` object, and passing it to the `json` parameter of `requests.post` will encode that string as JSON *again*. See

```python
response = requests.post(url, json={"foo": 1})
print(response.request.body)

response = requests.post(url, json='{"foo": 1}')
print(response.request.body)
```

Will print

```
b'{"foo": 1}'
b'"{\\"foo\\": 1}"'
```

What you must do, to send that JSON data correctly, is

```python
data = df.to_json(orient='records')
response = requests.post(url, data=data.encode())
```

or actually convert the `DataFrame` to a `dict`

```python
data = df.to_dict(orient='records')
response = requests.post(url, json=data)
```

Comment: I would like to add that the `json` argument for `requests.post` is more catered for `dict` types, while `data` argument is for payload that has already been finalised into the intended form.

Comment: Indeed, I edited my answer to add another solution that properly uses the `json` parameter by converting the `DataFrame` into a dict.

Answer (score 0):

JSON object is nothing but a dictionary in python and flask is framework written python 
Accordingly, the json library exposes the dump() method for writing data to files. There is also a dumps() method (pronounced as “dump-s”) for writing to a Python string.
Simple Python objects are translated to JSON according to a fairly intuitive conversion.

```
Python          JSON
dict            object
list,tuple      array
str             string
int,long,float  number
True            true
False           false
None            null
```

so depending upon what is extracted from json python variable behaves accordingly,
like in first case 
`data = data.iloc[[0]].to_json(orient='records')` data variable is nothing but a string,
so this is why `res = requests.post(url, json=data)`  shows such behaviour here
In second Case
`data = {'name':'foo','age':99}` it's dictionary 
so this why
`res = requests.post(url, json=data)` shows such behaviour